# Convert the String Monday 5 October to date using Google Apps Script

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I need to convert the date string of type WEEKDAY DATE MONTHNAME, Example: from "Monday 5 October" to date object.

I have tried with

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date("Monday 5 October"), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

How do I convert it, I am ok using V8 apps script engine

Comment: What is the year?

Comment: The year is a Current year always

Answer (score 1):

The [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) accepts timestamp strings formatted according to [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

There are many ways to convert your string to date, but probably one of the simplest is appending the current year to your string, using [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear):

```
const source = "Monday 5 October";
const date = new Date(`${source} ${new Date().getFullYear()}`);
```

#### Reference:

- [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)
- [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)